# Why can't Coq figure out symmetry of the equality by itself?

Tags: coq, formal-languages, formal-verification, coq-tactic, formal-methods

Suppose we're trying to formalize some (semi)group-theoretic properties, like this:

```
Section Group.

Variable A: Type.
Variable op: A -> A -> A.

Definition is_left_neutral  (e: A) := forall x: A, (op e x) = x.
Definition is_right_neutral (e: A) := forall x: A, x = (op x e).

Lemma uniqueness_of_neutral:
  forall a b: A, (is_left_neutral a) -> (is_right_neutral b) -> (a = b).
Proof.
  intro; intro.
  intros lna rnb.
  elim lna with b; elim rnb with a.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

End Group.
```

It works just fine, **but**, if we reverse the equation in either of the above definitions, i.e. replace the definitions with

```
Definition is_left_neutral  (e: A) := forall x: A, x = (op e x).
```

and

```
Definition is_right_neutral (e: A) := forall x: A, (op x e) = x.
```

respectively, the proof fails at `reflexivity`, since one or both of the `elim` applications do nothing.
Sure there is a workaround for it, based on `assert`, but that's... too much effort and simply annoying...

- Is there a reason why the involved Coq tactics (`elim`, `case`, etc.) are so much sensitive to the order? I suppose, it shouldn't slow down the tactics any noticeably (<< 2 times).
- Is there a way to make them apply `symmetry` automatically, where needed, without bothering me about it every time? Couldn't find any mention of this issue in the manual.

Comment: Why did you choose to use elim?  This is the bare-bone tool for reasoning about inductive notions.  It has a bare-bone behavior, and it is preferable that it stays that way, for didactic purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, using `elim` to manipulate equality is cumbersome.  Here is how I would write your proof, using `rewrite`, and changing the definition of `is_left_neutral`.

```
Section Group.

Variable A: Type.
Variable op: A -> A -> A.

Definition is_left_neutral  (e: A) := forall x: A, op e x = x.
Definition is_right_neutral (e: A) := forall x: A, op x e = x.

Lemma uniqueness_of_neutral:
  forall a b: A, is_left_neutral a -> is_right_neutral b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros a b lna rnb.
  now rewrite <- (lna b), rnb.
Qed.

End Group.
```

Notice the `<-` in the first rewrite: it tells Coq to rewrite from right-to-left insead of left-to-right.  When you use `elim`, you can essentially only rewrite in one direction (right-to-left), which leads to the behavior that you saw.

I can't think right now of a reason for only trying one direction in the rewrite tactic, but I do not think it is for performance reasons.  In any case, you can define your own variant of `rewrite`, which tries to rewrite left-to-right, and then right-to-left, if that does not work:

```
Section Group.

Variable A: Type.
Variable op: A -> A -> A.

Definition is_left_neutral  (e: A) := forall x: A, op e x = x.
Definition is_right_neutral (e: A) := forall x: A, op x e = x.

Ltac my_rewrite t :=
  first [ rewrite t | rewrite <- t ].

Lemma uniqueness_of_neutral:
  forall a b: A, is_left_neutral a -> is_right_neutral b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros a b lna rnb.
  now my_rewrite (lna b); my_rewrite rnb.
Qed.

End Group.
```

Comment: Yes, `rewrite <- lna, rnb.` does the job (with `<-` if `op` is on "the other" side). And thanks for the smarter version of `rewrite`! -- Will try to apply the ideas to the other proofs (where I can't just change the definitions), maybe get rid of some `assert`s, and see what can be done for the more complicated tactics.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky This a job for the [`congruence`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#congruence) tactic. If you `Print uniqueness_of_neutral.` after using it, you'll see another proof of the lemma -- by transitivity of equality.